# Three equal segments on this angle, explanation for solution needed

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We're given an angle $\angle BAC$. We want to construct $D \in \overrightarrow{AB}$ and $E \in \overrightarrow{AC}$ such that $CE=DE=DB$. This is Euclidea's problem 15.4 and I have the solution but I don't understand it, here is a solution:

[image]

we construct circle $\gamma = \odot (B,\overline{AC})$ and mark point $X = \gamma \cap \overline{AB}$

we then draw line $r$, such that $X \in r \parallel AC$

we draw circle $\omega = \odot (C,\overline{CB})$ and mark point $Y = \omega \cap r$

point $D$ is in the perpendicular bissector of $YB$ and on line $AB$.

Why is that?

People who want solutions for Euclidea can check [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3An2r_7h898)

Comment: The key point is to show that CED is part of a rhombus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to answer the question "Why is that?" in the following manner. First of all, assuming we have the points $D,E$ on the sides $AB,AC$ with $BD=DE=EC$ we will construct $Y,X$, and show their properties match those from the construction. So if there is a solution, it must follow the prescribed receipt. Secondly, we perform the prescribed receipt (from the question and from the first point) till the end, also introducing $E$ in the obvious unique manner, and show that $BD=DE=EC$. So we have two proposition, let us state them explicitly in detail.

> The points $A,B,C$ are given. Furthermore, points $D$ on the segment $AB$, $E$ on $AC$ are given, so that $BD=DE=EC$. Consider $Y$, the reflection of $B$ w.r.t. $CD$. Draw the parallel $r$ through $Y$ to $AC$, it intersects $AB$ in a point $X$.
>
> **Then:** $XD=AE$ and $XB=AC$.

*Proof:* Denote by $a$ and by $2e$ the (measures of) angles $a=\widehat{BAC}$, and $2e=\widehat{CED}$.

[image: Construction euclidea problem MSE 4670220]

Then the angles in $C,D$ in the isosceles triangle $\Delta CED$ are the complements of $e$, $\hat C=\hat D=\bar e:=90^\circ-e$. Also, $\widehat{EDA}=\widehat{CED}-\widehat{BAC}=2e-a$. So $\widehat{CDA}= \bar e+(2e-a)=90^\circ+e-a$. This is also half of the angle in $D$ in $\Delta DBY$, so the equal angles in $B,Y$ in this last triangle are each $a-e$. The angle $a=\widehat{AXY}$ is finally the sum of $\widehat{XYB}$ and $\widehat{XBY}$, so
$$
\widehat{XYD}= a- 2(a-e)=2e-a=\widehat{EDA}\ .
$$
To conclude now that $EA=XD$ the simplest way is to use the sine theorem for $\Delta EAD$, and $\Delta DXY$:
$$
\frac{EA}{ED}=
\frac{\sin (2e-a)}{\sin a}
=
\frac{\sin (2e-a)}{\sin (180^\circ-a)}
=
\frac{XD}{DY}\ .
$$
Now we use $ED=DB=DY$ to get $EA=XD$, and finally $AC=AE+EC=XD+DB=XB$.

$\square$

The points $X,Y$ correspond to those from the question.

---

Conversely, we show that the construction from the question is working.
(At each point, only properties of the construction may be used as arguments.)
Here is explicitly the complete statement.

> Consider the points $A,B,C$ in the plane. We assume (to fit the figure) $AB\ge AC$. Construct first the point $A$ on $AB$ such that $AC=BX$. Construct the parallel $r$ through $X$ to $AC$, and let $Y$ be the point on it with $CY=CB$. (There are in general two such points. In order to match the figure from the question, we make an assumption.) We assume that $Y$ is in the half-plane w.r.t. $AB$ that does not contain $C$. The perpendicular bisector of the segment $BY$ intersects $AB$ in a point $D$. In particular $DB=DY$. The perpendicular bisector of $CD$ intersects $AC$ in a point $E$.
>
> **Then:** $BD=DE=EC$.

*Proof:* The picture is as follows:

[image: Construction euclidea problem MSE 4670220]

Again, we denote by $a$ the angle $\widehat{BAC}$, by $2e$ the angle $\widehat{CED}$. Then the angles in $C,D$ in $\Delta CED$ are $\bar e$, $2e$ is exterior to $\Delta AED$ in $E$, so $\widehat{EDA}=2e-a$, this leads to the value of the half of $\hat D$ in the isosceles triangle $\Delta DBY$, so the angles in $B,Y$ are each $a-e$. Finally, since $a=\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{AXY}$, we compute $\widehat{XYD}=2e-a$. The sine theorem in $\Delta AED$ and $\Delta XDY$ gives now the needed transition from proportions on $AB$ to proportions on $AC$:
$$
\frac {XD}{DB}
= \frac {XD}{DY}
= \frac {\sin (2e-a)}{\sin(180^\circ -a)}
= \frac {\sin (2e-a)}{\sin a}
= \frac {AE}{ED}
= \frac {AE}{EC}\ .
$$
From here, adding one on each side,
$$
\frac {XB}{DB} =
\frac {XD}{DB} +1=
\frac {AE}{EC} +1=
\frac {AC}{EC}\ .
$$
But by construction, $XB=AC$, so $DB=EC$.

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

1. Construct the ||gm CABZ so that circle $γ(B, AC=BZ)$ can be drawn.

[image]

2. Produce EC to V such that EC = CV.
3. Produce ED to cut the red dotted circle $\omega$ at R. Note that ED = DR = radius of $\omega$.
4. Form the $\triangle EVR$ and let VR cut $\omega$ at U.
5. By midpoint theorem, CD || VR.
6. Let EU cut CD at S.
7. By angle in semi-circle, $\angle ESC = \angle SUR = 90^0$.
8. Since DS is a line from center (D) and is perpendicular to the chord EU, it bisects EU.
9. With the fact that DE = DU, CEDU is not just a kite but a rhombus.

Comment: I still need to think how that relates to the original question without assuming the result we want to check ($CE=ED=DB$)

Comment: @hellofriends ED = DB because they are the radii of the same circle. It remains to be shown is whether CE = ED.